# Json array build

Tags: javascript, json

I have a raw "entry" and "exit" data as json for person(sorted by date).

```
[{
   id: 1,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:30:48.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.202",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
}, // the exit object is missing for id=1. I need to create same object as exit vice versa...
{
   id: 2,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:35:44.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 3,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:36:40.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.202",
   gateType: "exit",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 4,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:37:22.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 5,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:38:55.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "exit",
   personId: 207
}]
```

It needs to go like entry -> exit -> entry -> exit. 
But sometimes some "exit" or some "entry" objects are missing.

So i am trying to detect the missing "objects" and create an array for bulk insert as the difference would be 0 second and would fail.

So, the solution should be for above case;

```
[
   [1, "2015-11-26T16:30:48.000Z", "192.168.0.202", "exit", 207], 
   //... if there are any more..
]
```

Comment: Where is your array  of array creation code?

Comment: Actually i have created with for loop but i am trying to do it in a functional way. But i am not sure if reduce would be enough or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
var json_obj = [{
   id: 1,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:30:48.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.202",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
},
{
   id: 2,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:35:44.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 3,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:36:40.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.202",
   gateType: "exit",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 4,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:37:22.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "entry",
   personId: 207
}, {
   id: 5,
   dateTime: "2015-11-26T16:38:55.000Z",
   gateNumber: "192.168.0.201",
   gateType: "exit",
   personId: 207
}];


your_new_array = json_obj.map(function(obj){
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('exit'))
     {
       obj.exit = 'exit value';
     }
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('entry'))
     {
       obj.entry = 'entry value';
     }
    return obj;
});
console.log(your_new_array);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4f5Lpcge/ for fiddle :) I hope it helps!